# How to import an amd module in ember-cli?

Tags: ember-cli

I am building an EmberJS application with the great help of `ember-cli`, which is great, but I have an error and I cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I do in my broccoli file:

```
app.import('vendor/underscore/underscore.js', {
    exports: {
        "underscore": [
            "underscore"
        ]
    }
});
```

and then in one of my controllers:

```
import _ from "underscore";
```

`ember-cli` builds my application.

But when I go to the controller using underscore, I get the error:

> Error: Could not find module underscore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/underscore/underscore.js',
  production:  'vendor/underscore/underscore.min.js'
}, {
  'underscore': [
    'default'
  ]
});
```

This will at least give "import _ from 'underscore';" a chance to work. If you choose an AMD or ES6 version of underscore/lodash, list which modules you wish to import with 'default'.

EDIT:

Is it crucial that you use underscore? Why I ask, I'm using lodash with one Ember-cli project, and it is working fine.

```
Console> bower install lodash --save
```

then in Brocfile:

```
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.js',
  production:  'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js'
}, {
  'lodash': [
    'default'
  ]
});


//or:
app.import('vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js');
```

As for underscore - there was [an issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/943) with devDependencies not being bundled, of which underscore is one.

Answer (score 3):

I got this from locks on #emberjs IRC.

https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify

In your project:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
npm install --save-dev underscore
```

In your controller:

```
import _ from "npm:underscore";
```

Then you can use _.  For example:  `_.each([1,2,3], alert);`.  I took everything out I had manually added to brocfile and package.json.  Apparently this will do it for you.  Crazy!

Comment: The issue here is that ember cli recommends using bower as your dependency manager. I think it's a good approach, but it fragments your dependencies and makes them more difficult to follow.

At this point in time I've accepted using libraries such as lodash/underscore as globals by importing them in the `Brocfile` and declaring them with `/* global _ */` in order to appease jshint.

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of ember (I am using 2.11) it is possible to load AMD in UMD wrappers using

```
app.import('bower_components/js-md5/js/md5.js', {using: [{ 
   transformation: 'amd', as: 'js-md5' 
}]});
```

And in your code

```
import md5 from 'js-md5';
```

In your case of underscore it should look like:

```
app.import('vendor/underscore/underscore.js', {using: [{ 
   transformation: 'amd', as: 'underscore' 
}]});
```