# Import dependencies in ember-cli (e.g., import math.js)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, amd, mathjs

I am puzzled about importing dependencies in ember-cli, especially about the standard AMD case, as mentioned in the [official Ember Cli document](http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies). The document doesn't provide much of examples, and seems to me it assumes the readers have good knowledge about AMD, which is not the case for me. My immediate use case is import math.js. Unfortunately, the [official document of math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html) doesn't provide example about importing with Ember Cli. Then, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718808/how-to-import-an-amd-module-in-ember-cli) with relatively clearer examples, in particular, the following one seems quite relevant.

```
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.js',
  production:  'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js'
}, {
  'lodash': [
    'default'
  ]
});
```

Then, I did similar thing with math.js like below:

```
app.import({
  development: 'bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.js',
  production:  'bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.min.js'
}, {
  'mathjs': [
    'default'
  ]
});
```

However, it doesn't work. When I tried to use it with

```
import mathjs from 'mathjs'
```

I got an error. Eventually, I used the following solution:

```
// Brocfile.js
app.import('bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.min.js');

// some controller.js
var math = window.math
```

Although above solution works, I don't like it as it may be subject to name conflict. Besides, based on math.js's document, it seems to me it should support standard AMD type of import.

So, my questions are the following.
1. In the `lodash` example above, what does the `'default'` mean? Is that a general reference to whatever exported in the corresponding module? How can I tell whether I can use it in general (for example, math.js)?
2. Is it true that if a module supports require.js, then it is a standard AMD module? If so, given code like below:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    mathjs: 'path/to/mathjs',
  }
});
require(['mathjs'], function (math) {
  // use math.js
  math.sqrt(-4); // 2i
});
```

how can I map it to Ember Cli code?

Comment: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3563 <- may apply

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain but since mathjs does not expose/support a named AMD module you can't use the extra syntax in `app.import`.

You have two options:

1. [ember-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browserify) (if the library supports CommonJS - which mathjs does)
2. "shimming" the dependant library yourself

### 1. ember-browserify

1. Install ember-browserify

   `ember install ember-browserify`
2. Install the CommonJS library as an NPM package

   `npm install --save-dev mathjs`
3. Use the NPM package with regular `import` syntax

   `import mathjs from 'npm:mathjs';`

### 2. Shimming

What you need to do is "shim" the library to make it available via `import` statements. I still don't know what the word shim means <:

If you're interested in creating a bower package, e.g. `ember-cli-mathjs-shim` you could then use that and give others the ability to use it too. Some examples of this are:

[`ember-cli-shims`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-shims)

[`ember-cli-moment-shim`](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim)

[`ember-cli-sockjs-shim`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-cli-sockjs-shim)

But if you're not comfortable doing that, I would recommend adding the following to your project:

`vendor/shims/math.js` - Create a `shims` folder under `vendor` (vendor is where your dependancies go that don't come from NPM or Bower - and the Brocfile doesn't appear to be able to `app.import` from anywhere other than here - e.g. `app/shims` or simple `shims` at the root level doesn't work)

`vendor/shims/math.js`

```
(function() {
  /* globals define, math */

  function mathJSModule() {
    'use strict';

    return { 'default': math };
  }

  define('mathjs', [], mathJSModule);

})();
```

`Brocfile.js`

```
app.import('bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.js');
app.import('vendor/shims/math.js', {
  exports: {
    'mathjs': [ 'default' ]
  }
});
```

The order here is important.

Comment: this answer saved me. didn't know why I never though of it. Now I can have just one shims file that i can add all my various shims too.. no more half browserify half bower for visual libraries.

Comment: Just as an FYI, a "shim" is a piece of wood or other material that fills in a gap (normally when building something or trying to get a piece of furniture to be level). So when we talk about a browser shim, we're talking about a library that fills in the gaps that a browser has to make it compliant with standards.