# Create shim for ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to create shim for [getstream](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js) library for ember-cli as **@jmurphyau** answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584671/4950029).

I `bower install getstream`, then create file

`vendor/shims/getstream.js`

```
(function() { 
  /* globals define, getstream */

  function getstreamModule() { 

    'use strict';

    return getstream; // <-- got error here
  }

  define('getstream', [], getstreamModule);

})();
```

and add lines to `Brocfile.js`

```
app.import('bower_components/getstream/dist/js_min/getstream.js');
app.import('vendor/shims/getstream.js', {
  exports: {
   'getstream': [ 'default' ]
  }
});
```

and try to `import Stream from 'getstream';` in route.

Got `Uncaught ReferenceError: getstream is not defined` in getstream.js

What's going wrong and how it could be fixed? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ember-browsify?

That library doesn't look like it exposes a global variable called `getstream` which is why your getting that error.

It does however look like it supports CommonJS module syntax so ember-browserify should work.

1. Install ember-browserify

   `ember install ember-browserify`
2. Install the CommonJS library as an NPM package

   `npm install --save-dev getstream`
3. Use the NPM package with regular `import` syntax

   `import getstream from 'npm:getstream';`

Comment: Yeah, I know this approach, but something goes wrong with `getstream` library. 
On `ember server` error is raised: 
Cannot find module 'browser-request' from '`<my_app>`/node_modules/getstream/src'
Error: 

Cannot find module 'browser-request' from '`<my_app>`/node_modules/getstream/src'
    at `<my_app>`/node_modules/ember-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks, jmurphyau!

Comment: I find it works after adding `browser-request` to dependencies. [Commit](https://github.com/artych/stream-js/commit/7aa0be696c4926eeb1c06d83f17ad6723a5bd4d0)